# How to load a SOAP template to a SOAP message in Java?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am doing some web service testing work, so a SOAP request has to be created in Java. To automate some part of the SOAP message, only several fields need to be changed and the rest part stays static. So I am thinking of creating a SOAP template, and load it to Java.

Though, I was not able to figure out how to load that file directly to a `Message` object in Java.

The primary source that I am referring to:
the `Request.java` section in [SAAJ code example](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/SAAJ4.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming template.xml contains your request data, you can pass it this way:

```
SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse("file:///template.xml");
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
soapPart.setContent(domSource);
```

If you're not required to use SAAJ, your life would be much easier if you used JAX-WS utilities to generate proxy objects for you from the WSDL. Then you can invoke your requests on those objects just as though they were local methods. Here's a quick [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/) about it if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [SoapWS](https://github.com/reficio/soap-ws) library, this is much easier to test SOAP services with this library: